# Python Mediator pattern memory leak?

Tags: python, design-patterns, mediator

I have a few classes that communicate with each other over another class (something like the Mediator pattern).

Every class prints a message both when created and destroyed:

[image]

When I create a Mediator object, the Mediator holds references to all other objects, and all objects hold references to the Mediator.

After that, objects' destructors are not called when the program finishes:

[image]

Why is that? Is this a memory leak?

Comment: Sounds like you have circular references. Consider using `weakref` for the backwarks references.

Comment: And please post copy/pastable code instead of screenshots of your editor or whatever the heck that is.

Comment: Just to expand... when objects have forward and backward references, the reference count may never go to zero and they will not be deleted. The garbage collector tries to figure it out, but its not 100%.

Answer (score 2):

In your case the application is exiting, so all memory allocated to the python process by the OS will be freed once it terminates.

As to why there are no print statements, when the program exit it destroys the objects, I assume you are using the __del__ method to print the messages, and as noted by the Python documentation, those methods are not guaranteed to be called at program exit, [Link here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)

> object.__del__(self):
>
> ... It is not guaranteed that __del__() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

Comment: I think this is better boilded down into a comment.